# How Can I get created_time from this instagram json?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4, instagram

I got this json and `created_time` value show time in **integer** format not a in time formate but I want this created_time in proper format.
How to get **created_time** in proper format?

```
"filter"=>"Normal",
"created_time"=>"1421677966",
  "link"=>"http://instagram.com/p/yCfw5sKorK/",
  "likes"=>{
    "count"=>1,
    "data"=>[
      {
        "username"=>"nikhil.thombare",
        "profile_picture"=>"https://instagramimages-a.akamaihd.net/profiles/anonymousUser.jpg",
        "id"=>"1651917721",
        "full_name"=>"Nikhil Narendra Thombare"
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Time at](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Time.html#method-c-at)

```
Time.at(created_time)
```

Comment: Nope, I get "TypeError: can't convert String into an exact number" when `Time.at("1426311385")`

Comment: `Time.at(1426311385)` or `Time.at(your_variable.to_i)`

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Its actually a string when it comes down from Instagram's API.